# Executing more than one FrontendAction on a CompilerInstance in clang

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I have a single cpp file of about 100 lines with the following contents.

```
#include <clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/FrontendActions.h>
#include <iostream>

// The filename that will be processed (twice).
static const char* FILENAME = "simple.cpp";

// System header locations, you may need to
// adjust these.
static const char* SYSTEM_HEADERS[] =
{
    "/usr/include/c++/5.4.0",
    "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5.4.0",
    "/usr/include/c++/5.4.0/backward",
    "/usr/local/lib/clang/4.0.0/include",
    "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
    "/usr/include"
};

// Location for builtin headers. You may need to
// adjust this.
static const char* RESOURCE_DIR = "/usr/local/lib/clang/4.0.0";

// Uncomment this to see header search paths.
// #define PRINT_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS

// Constructs a CompilerInvocation
// that must be fed to a CompilerInstance.
clang::CompilerInvocation* makeInvocation();

// Executes a single SyntaxOnlyAction on
// the given CompilerInstance.
void secondCallThisFunctionFails(clang::CompilerInstance& instance);

int main()
{
    using namespace clang;

    CompilerInstance instance;

    instance.createDiagnostics();

    instance.setInvocation(makeInvocation());
    instance.getFrontendOpts().Inputs.emplace_back
    (
        FILENAME, 
        FrontendOptions::getInputKindForExtension(FILENAME)
    );

    // First call is OK.
    secondCallThisFunctionFails(instance);

    // Second call results in assertion failures.
    secondCallThisFunctionFails(instance);

    return 0;
}

clang::CompilerInvocation* makeInvocation()
{
    using namespace clang;
    auto invocation = new CompilerInvocation();

    invocation->TargetOpts->Triple = llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple();
    invocation->setLangDefaults(
        *invocation->getLangOpts(), 
        IK_CXX, 
        llvm::Triple(invocation->TargetOpts->Triple), 
        invocation->getPreprocessorOpts(), 
        LangStandard::lang_cxx11);

    auto& headerSearchOpts = invocation->getHeaderSearchOpts();

    #ifdef PRINT_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS
        headerSearchOpts.Verbose = true;
    #else
        headerSearchOpts.Verbose = false;
    #endif

    headerSearchOpts.UseBuiltinIncludes = true;
    headerSearchOpts.UseStandardSystemIncludes = true;
    headerSearchOpts.UseStandardCXXIncludes = true;
    headerSearchOpts.ResourceDir = RESOURCE_DIR;

    for (const auto sytemHeader : SYSTEM_HEADERS)
    {
        headerSearchOpts.AddPath(sytemHeader, frontend::System, false, false);
    }

    return invocation;
}

void secondCallThisFunctionFails(clang::CompilerInstance& instance)
{
    using namespace clang;
    SyntaxOnlyAction action;
    if (instance.ExecuteAction(action))
    {
        std::cout << "Action succeeded.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Action failed.\n";
    }
}
```

As you can see, the main function is quite simple, and calls a function twice at the end. The second time this function is called I get an assertion failure, which surprises me.

The contents of the file `simple.cpp` is

```
// test wether we actually configured C++11 or greater
#include <thread>
int main() { return 0; }
```

The output of this program on my machine is:

```
Action succeeded.
clangapitest: ../tools/clang/lib/Basic/SourceManager.cpp:819: clang::FileID clang::SourceManager::getFileIDLoaded(unsigned int) const: Assertion `0 && "Invalid SLocOffset or bad function choice"' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The problem is: *I want to execute more than one action on a CompilerInstance. What state do I have to reset in order to not get assertion failures?*

To build it yourself you have to link with some static clang and llvm libraries. Here's the CMakeLists.txt file if interested:

```
add_clang_executable(clangapitest clangapitest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(clangapitest clangFrontend)
```

I made a new directory `path/to/llvm/tools/clang/tools/clangapitest` and adjusted the CMakeLists.txt file in `path/to/llvm/tools/clang/tools/CMakeLists.txt` to have an extra line `add_subdirectory(clangapitest)`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out. In the [doxygen documentation of CompilerInstance::ExecuteAction](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CompilerInstance.html#acab2d9d69ec889a7034634036720ffc5), it states that an invocation object and diagnostics object should have been initialized, and no other state (hence no source nor filemanager). So the following works:

```
SyntaxOnlyAction action;
instance.setSourceManager(nullptr);
instance.createDiagnostics();
if (instance.ExecuteAction(action))
{
    std::cout << "Action succeeded.\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Action failed.\n";
}
```